# Getting the next radio button be checked after the radio button selected has been disabled

Tags: jquery, html

So, I have a pretty simple add and delete of set of pictures. They currently have radio button that will let the user select which will be the default picture. Here is a simple html for this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="vatop aleft">
            <table>                                            
                <tr>
                    <td><div id="pic1" class="picture" ><span>1</span></div></td>
                    <td><div id="pic2" class="picture" ><span>2</span></div></td>
                    <td><div id="pic3" class="picture" ><span>3</span></div></td>
                    <td><div id="pic4" class="picture" ><span>4</span></div></td>
                    <td><div id="pic5" class="picture" ><span>5</span></div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <!--JDO 12.12.2013 CWA-9448 -->
                    <td class="acenter"><input id="default1" type="radio" name="defaultpic" class="defaultpic" picnumber="1" /><span><!--This is where default text go--></span></td>
                    <td class="acenter"><input id="default2" type="radio" name="defaultpic" class="defaultpic" picnumber="2" disabled="disabled" /><span><!--This is where default text go--></span></td>
                    <td class="acenter"><input id="default3" type="radio" name="defaultpic" class="defaultpic" picnumber="3" disabled="disabled" /><span><!--This is where default text go--></span></td>
                    <td class="acenter"><input id="default4" type="radio" name="defaultpic" class="defaultpic" picnumber="4" disabled="disabled" /><span><!--This is where default text go--></span></td>
                    <td class="acenter"><input id="default5" type="radio" name="defaultpic" class="defaultpic" picnumber="5" disabled="disabled" /><span><!--This is where default text go--></span></td>
             <!--END-->
                       </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="aleft vabottom" colspan="5" style="padding-top: 15px;" >
                        <form id="uploadform" name="uploadForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="FileTransferHandler.ashx" target="pictureframe">
                            <input id="filepicture" name="filepicture" type="file" class="file" style="margin-right: 5px; width: 450px;" />
                            <select id="picturenumber" class="" style="margin-right: 5px; width: 80px;"></select>
                            <input id="uploadpicture" type="submit" value="{{UIT.[147743]}}" class="link" />
                            <a id="deletepicture" href="javascript:void(0)" rel="deletepicture" class="link" >{{UIT.[8397]}}</a>
                        </form>
                        <iframe id="pictureframe" name="pictureframe" src="about:blank" class="hidden"></iframe>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Now with this Im having a problem with having the default image deleted. For example i will upload three pictures and select the second picture as the default one then delete that picture, the picture was deleted but as my code chooses the next default image(which is the first picture since it has a picture) it is being selected but the radio button was not checked. See my code snippet for the delete:

```
var $deletepicture = $("#main-template #deletepicture");
$deletepicture.click(function () {
   $("#main-template #picturenumber option:selected").each(function () {
     _picnum = $(this).attr("code");
     //Remove the image, show the span, reset the filename attribute of the div
     $("#pic" + _picnum.toString() + " img").remove();
     $("#pic" + _picnum.toString()).find("span").show();
     $("#pic" + _picnum.toString()).removeAttr("filename");
     $("#pic" + _picnum.toString()).hide().show();
     //Choose another default
     $("#default" + _picnum.toString()).removeAttr('checked');
     $("#default" + _picnum.toString()).next().text('');
     $("#default" + _picnum.toString()).prop('disabled', true);
     for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
       var $div = $("#pic" + i.toString());
       if ($div.attr("filename") !== undefined) {

         $("#default" + i.toString()).attr('checked', 'checked');
         $("#default" + i.toString()).next().text(' Default');
         //JDO 12.12.2013 CWA-9437
         return false;
       }
   };
 });
});
```

I can see the 'Default' move from the second picture to the first picture but I am having a hard time letting the radio box be checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from jQuery 1.9 onwards, to activate a radio button, use:

```
$("#default" + i.toString()).prop("checked", true);
```

instead of

```
$("#default" + i.toString()).attr('checked', 'checked');
```

Comment: Thanks! That's a relief!

Comment: if this answer is sufficient for you, please mark it as accepted answer. If however you need further explanation... let me know :D